# No brakes/pedal goes to the floor

Tags: ford, brakes, troubleshooting, explorer

I just recently changed all my brake pads and calipers on my 2002 Ford Explorer.

I bled the calipers from rear passenger to front driver side. They feel good when the truck is off but as soon as I start the truck up there are no brakes. As far as I can tell there are no leaks and there is plenty of fluid in the reservoir.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You haven't fully bled the system or you haven't done it correctly would be my suggestion.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "no brakes"? Does the pedal go to the floor? Is there no bite to the brakes? Does it require a lot more force from your foot to stop?

Answer (score 1):

did the master cylinder run dry when you were changing the calipers? If so, you must remove it and bench bleed it. Then bleed the wheels. If you still have air, you'll have to do an ABS bleed procedure.

Comment: A fun way to bleed the master without taking it apart is to find a large parking lot, accelerate, and slam on the brakes a few times. Also works wonders for the ABS. (Though, if the brakes are completely non-functional, I can't really recommend this.) *(Professional driver on closed course. Do not attempt.)*